# How to find location of downloaded files on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, youtube-dl

I am using [YouTube-dl](https://github.com/scastillo/not-youtube-dl) with Python and Flask to download youtube videos and return them using the `send_file` function.

When running locally I have been using to get the file path:

```
username = getpass.getuser()
directories = os.listdir(rf'C:\\Users\\{username}')
```

I then download the video with YouTube-dl:

```
youtube_dl.YoutubeDL().download([link])
```

I then search the directory for the file based on the video code:

```
files = [file for file in directories]
code = link.split('v=')[1]
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.mp4') is True:
        try:
            code_section = file.split('-')[1].split('.mp4')[0]
            if code in code_section:
                return send_file(rf'C:\\Users\\{username}\\{file}')
        except:
            continue
```

Finally, I return the file:

```
return send_file(rf'C:\\Users\\{username}\\{file}')
```

to find the location of the downloaded file, but, on Heroku, this doesn't work - simply the directory doesn't exist. How would I find where the file is downloaded? Is there a function I can call? Or is there a set path it would go to?

Or alternatively, is there a way to set the download location with YouTube-dl?

Comment: if you are saving your data on your local PC it wont work you need to have a S3 account or a Dropbox etc.  datastorage .

Comment: @Shad0w with YouTube-dl you can only download to local pc. I think you need to find a way to find the download path of the YouTube file and replace the path in the send_file function with the path of the download. The C: directory will not exist on a Heroku app

Comment: @PythonIsBae I am kinda new to Heroku but from my research I understood that Heroku dose not support saving data on your PC and that you need a data storage even for images or files you need a data storage as S3 did you try your method before?

Comment: @Shad0w so how would GAP2002 upload to S3 once downloading the file? Sorry for getting in on the post but I had this problem before so interested to know.

Comment: @PythonIsBae I did read many pages and these are some of the site that explain how https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudinary https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3  https://realpython.com/migrating-your-django-project-to-heroku/#data-transfer I really was trying search for easier ways that is free and not confusing but I found nothing but that I need to link my heroku with my site cll them with ```gem```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since heroku is running Linux and not windows, you could attempt to download your files to your current working directory and then just send it from there.

The main tweak would be setting up some options in your YoutubeDL app:

```py
import os

opts = {
  "outtmpl": f"{os.getcwd()}/(title)s.(ext)s"
}

youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(opts).download([link])
```

That will download the file to your current working directory.
Then you can just upload it from your working directory using `return send_file(file)`.